# Sync SQLite with homemade Linux server

Tags: android, sqlite, server

I'm learning android and I want to know how I can make an app that gets values from a SQLite in a homemade Linux server (with a raspberry `PI`, I only want to test, not publish the app, and save that values in the device and if in the device any value is changed it has to be changed in the server too.

Comment: Sqlite on a Linux server? You mean MySQL?

Comment: Duplicate - [Android - Best way to sync SQLite with MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26706506/android-best-way-to-sync-sqlite-with-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your IP configuration, since SQL have a connection to an IP adress, you have to be on a local network by using the local IP of your linux server, otherwise, for a public connection you must have a static public IP for your server, which you can only get by buying it with your internet provider (not recommended) or instead you can buy a space in an online server, which you can use phpMyAdmin or another SQL administrator which you can edit via ftp and they give you the IP or the DNS for a public connection.

Comment: Dynamic dns is free. Regardless, this doesn't attempt to answer the question for syncing data in android.