# SQLite online synchronization

Tags: java, android, sqlite, synchronization

I have created an Android application works on database... Initially I just want to access the databases locally so make use of the SQLite local database.But now, I want to synchronize my database with online.Please help me to sync my DB to online with the most easiest way.

Comment: Your question is too generic. Please be more specific about database versions, libraries, APIs, and what it means to "synchronize my database with online". And provide example code if you think it could be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

you can refer this link to get more details

[Android - Best way to sync SQLite with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26706506/android-best-way-to-sync-sqlite-with-mysql)

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-sync-sqlite-database-with-server/