# Does the time in which response is received in Android from the web service depends on the library that we use for httpconnection?

Tags: android, execution-time, androidhttpclient, android-webservice

This may be a very basic question. But please clear a doubt that I have. Does the time in which response is received in Android App from the web service depends on the library we use for http connection? I mean is some library give faster response than others?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206397/what-is-the-most-robust-http-library-for-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Volley library that is recommended by Google.

Here is nice example of caching your response. How to use this

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: So do you suggest that the speed depends on the library that we use?

Comment: Yes it depends on what library you use. Volley uses concept of caching so it is fast from other library.